# .htaccess block acess to certain common subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess

lets say I have a directory structure like below, I want to block access to dira and dirc in each users directory but not block dirb ... how would I do this with .htaccess

```
1/wwwroot/
2     files/
3        users/
4           bill/
5              dira
6              dirb
7              dirc
8           tom/
9              dira
10             dirb
11             dirc
12          fred/
13             dira
14             dirb
15             dirc
```

I tried this without success any thoughts?

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/files/users/*/dira/*
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/files/users/*/dirc/*
```

This blocks dirb as well

Web access on a lamp stack btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `*` won't work. You need to use a `.` for "any character":

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/files/users/.*/dira/.*
```

Or even better yet, maybe

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^.*/files/users/[^/]+/dira/.*
```

Comment: That worked, just realized i neglected to select it.  Thanks!!